# Migrating Entity Framework without Migration Files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on a project which is using Entity Framework code first for its data structure. It was created with code first, but was never migrated again and only has its initial migration data stored. Since then, the database has been modified directly through server explorer in VS2015.

There is no migration information about any changes and the database has critical information which I cannot lose.

Which brings me to my Questions.

**If I create a new migration and update the database from it, will it wipe all changes which were not recorded in migrations and still leave the changes which were made as well?**

Comment: but you Did not mention what is the error ?when you try to add migration version to update database  ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question isn't phrased correctly, my goal is to make a new migration to update the database, someone in my company has not maintained via migrations but directly, now I want to do migrations, I want to keep all changes and update also. My question is will it wipe the direct changes? I can't try it because I don't want to accidentally delete sensitive data.

Comment: should be backup your sensitive data,cause  first time code first  migration .create new database as your model ,if you want to keep your data you should be use database first migration .

Comment: @NazmulHasan It's not necessary to do a database first migration if you want to keep your data.  A properly scripted code first migration will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of your question is a bit sketchy, but I will make some assumptions in order to help you along.  Please correct where I am wrong.

I assume that you want to keep the data which resulted from the changes which were effected directly to the database, but you do not want to keep the changes that was effected to the database - in other words: keep the data but not the datastructures.

## My advice is as follows

- Always perform a full backup of your database when you are about to do something you are uncertain about.
- If you can identify the tables you want to update, you can always use the [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) statement to create a quick backup of the specific tables only.  These tables will not be removed when you do a EF database migration unless you explicitly script the deletion.
- You can build the [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) statement into your EF migration via the [`Sql()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql(v=vs.113).aspx) method, or you can manually run the command against the database.

## More information:

- [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) to learn about EF code first migrations in general
- [Click here](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/) for a comprehensive code first migration reference

Answer (score 1):

I believe following two posts will help you.

EF 4.3 Migration Walkthrough : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

### update:

Code First Migrations with an existing database
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx